# Default Jersery ouput MIME type as xml

Tags: xml, jersey, http-status-code-404

When Jersey returns a 404 (when a @Path is not found), it returns the 404 as HTML by default. However, because the client of our web service expects XML for everything [which we handle using @Produces("application/xml") in our code], we want to configure Jersey to send all of it's *default* error content as XML also.

How do you configure Jersey to do this. And if there is no way, how is it recommended that this be accomplished?

Comment: What is the web container that you are using? For Tomcat, you can specify a 404 page which contains the desired xml.

Answer (score 0):

For tomcat, you could try doing this in your web.xml

```
 <error-page> 
 <error-code>404</error-code> 
 <location>/404.jsp</location> 
 </error-page>
```

Your 404.jsp could contain the xml response expected by the Client.